# Get HTML Code from WebSite and remove unnecessary Code - Only display the Table in WebView

Tags: android, html, regex, jsoup

I am trying to get my app to sync itself with a website, and display only the table of a website. Example: Normal HTML framework, and the table is inside a div#table, so I did it pretty simple and built the HTML Framework:

```
String html = "<html> " +
        "<head>" +
        "</head>" +
        "<body style=\"background-color: transparent\">" +
        "?body" +
        "</body>" +
        "</html>";
```

And then I tried to replace the ?body with the table, but here's my problem: I have no clue how to do that and then load it into a transparent WebView. I found a little bit code online, and tried to get it working for my case, so here's that:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    List<String> links = new ArrayList();
    setContentView(SliderCreator.createSlider(R.layout.activity_news, this));
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.newsWebView);
    wv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    try {
        String finalHTML = getIntent().getStringExtra("html");
        if (!finalHTML.contains("<html>")) {
            String css = "";
            for(String link : links) {
                css+=Utils.getHTML(link);
            }
            finalHTML = html.replace("?body", getIntent().getStringExtra("html")).replace("?css", css);
        }
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //open URLs in external Browser
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                return true;
            }
        });
        wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", finalHTML, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "An error occured...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

But that doesn't work.. Can somebody help me out get that working for me?
(Btw.: I tried it with RegEx, didn't work, I tried it with JSoup, didn't work either...)

Comment: Did you try to debug it? Are you sure that you get the right value from ` String finalHTML = getIntent().getStringExtra("html");`?

Comment: Add some println's and see if the HTML you load into the WebView is really what you what. And what exactly "Doesn't work" ?

Comment: @JonasCz I am fairly new to programming, I just added the println and yeah, you're right, I don't get anything I think. I think the problem is that I maybe need an AsyncTask, but I don't know how to do that.. So what doesn't work is that I only display that one div tag in my webview, I want to remove the other stuff.

Comment: if you show us the code where you put your HTML into the Intent (where you add the `html` extra string into your Intent, probably in another Activity, maybe I can tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @JonasCz I'm just gonna hardcode it. xD

Comment: Hardcoding is probably not the best idea if you want to change it later or make it dynamic, and it may result in messy code But if it works for you, go for it.

Comment: @JonasCz Yeah, it only changes when the Major is changed, so I guess that would be worth an update..

Answer (score 0):

try using HTML Agility Pack if not working with RegEx

**Please note**, your RegEx might not work the desired way if the text contains nested table tags